# Two lines within the frametitle of a beamer frame?

Tags: beamer

I am not too good in LaTeX, so sorry for this -maybe- ugly source.

I am trying to get a line break (`FrameTitle<break>FrameSubTitle`) within the title of a frame.

My MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}


\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{  
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.75ex,dp=1.375ex]{title in head/foot}
    
      \ifx \insertsubsection \empty
         \hspace*{2ex}\insertframetitle \hfill {\tiny\insertframenumber} \hspace*{1ex}
      \else
         \hspace*{2ex}\hbox{\insertframetitle \\ \insertframesubtitle} \hfill {\tiny\insertframenumber} \hspace*{1ex} \fi
        
    \end{beamercolorbox}}

\begin{document}

    \section{Section}
    
    \subsection{Subsection}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{\insertsection}
        \framesubtitle{\insertsubsection}
        Frame
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%  
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=4ex,dp=1.375ex]{title in head/foot}
      \ifx \insertsubsection \empty
         \hspace*{2ex}\insertframetitle \hfill {\tiny\insertframenumber} \hspace*{1ex}
      \else
         \hspace*{2ex}\shortstack[l]{\insertframetitle \\ \insertframesubtitle} \hfill 
         {\tiny\insertframenumber} \hspace*{1ex} \fi
```

[image]